# Select on hstore column is not working (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-hstore/) to learn about the hstore feature.

I enabled the extension and can insert data with no problem.

However once I try to select data out of the hstore column like this:

```
SELECT attr -> 'ISBN-13' AS isbn
FROM books;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: public.hstore -> unknown LINE 23:  attr -> 'ISBN-13' AS isbn
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm confident, that the extension is correctly enabled, because otherwise I wouldn't even be able to create tables with hstore columns.

The full code to create the table, insert data and select it:

```
--DROP TABLE books;   
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;    

CREATE TABLE books (
 id serial primary key,
 title VARCHAR (255),
 attr public.hstore
);


INSERT INTO books (title, attr)
VALUES
 (
 'PostgreSQL Tutorial',
 '"paperback" => "243",
    "publisher" => "postgresqltutorial.com",
    "language"  => "English",
    "ISBN-13"   => "978-1449370000",
 "weight"    => "11.2 ounces"'
 );

-- Error occurs here
SELECT
 attr -> 'ISBN-13' AS isbn
FROM
 books;
--
```

Version:

```
PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit
```

Comment: Works for me: https://imgur.com/a/QIWyE8n How exactly did you install the extension? Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create extension` statement you used.

Comment: Edited. I also tried doing the query through terminal to no avail.

Comment: Check if extension created operators for itself: `SELECT (SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = oprright), * FROM pg_operator WHERE oprleft = (SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'hstore')-- AND oprname = '->'`

Comment: Output of that operators query: https://i.imgur.com/YbZ460Y.png

Comment: Maybe you have something broken with casts from `unknown`. Try accessing your hstore value like that: `attr -> 'ISBN-13'::text`

Comment: No change sadly. I'll try doing a full reinstall later tonight.

Comment: Maybe they aren't in your search path? If I do this `SET search_path = '';` I get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that you always qualify `hstore` with the schema name `public` leads me to think that that schema is not on your `search_path`.

Try using `OPERATOR(public.->)` instead of `->` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I changed the default search_path earlier beacuse I was too lazy to type my own scheme in front of every table name all the time. Changed it back to public and the original query works. Thanks!

Comment: You can have more than one schema in the `search_path`, then tables in all schemas can be accessed without schema qualification.